# How do I cover nail holes in composite trim in a wet location?

Tags: trim, hole

We put up some composite trim using an 18 gauge air nailer, however, some of the nails did not go in all the way, mostly due to operator inexperience.  What's the best way to cover up/remove the nails that are not countersunk?  And after they get countersunk, what's the best thing to fill the holes with?  This will be in a wet location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Countersink with a nailset, struck with a hammer.

[image: nailset]

Fill with painters caulk.

[image: painters caulk]

Comment: Painters caulk can be messy and cumbersome.  For small jobs they make wax filler pens that are cheap and easier to use IMHO.

Comment: If it's MDF, they are going to paint it. If they are going to paint it, you can't use wax. If you don't like painters caulk, I would use latex wood filler, but that shrinks and generally takes two coats.

Comment: I like to use lightweight spakle to fill nail holes. Apply it with your fingertip, let it dry for 10 mins then smooth it off with a damp cloth. Sanding is not usually needed if you use the damp cloth before it hardens too much.  You can paint it in one hour. Only use this product on surfaces to be painted, not stained.  Use a pre-colored filler paste or crayon on stained trim.

Answer (score 5):

As for the second question regarding filling the holes after countersinking:

Use DAP Painter's Putty '53' - pull out a portion the size of a large marble, shape it into a sphere or ball, and then use it like an eraser on your countersunk nail holes.  If you rub the putty ball back and forth along your trim over the countersunk nail hole, you'll slowly fill the hole with the putty and leave a smooth surface appropriate for painting.